How to "fix" incorrect datetimes and timezones in Postgres SQL Database?
I believe I have made an error when inserting some data into a SQL table.
The column containing the error has a datetime timezone aware type, which for Postgres is timestamptz.
Here is an example data:
2023-10-24 00:00:00.000 +0100

It was created from a date, without time or timezone information. This is why the time has defaulted to 00:00:00.000, and the timezone information appears to have defaulted to BST (+0100) either because this is being picked up on the database server side, or on the client side, both machines presumably having change timezone last month.

Aside: Why do I know this is an error?
I realized that it isn't obvious from my question why this is an "error". As others have pointed out in the comments, there is actually an additional factor at play here, which I was not previously aware of.

Applications such as DBeaver have timezone translations embedded into them. By default my DBeaver instance has its timezone set to Europe/London.

This is important to be aware of (I was aware of it) but it is a red herring.
The real issue is that the client application logic is broken. At the present time I don't fully understand why and I need to investigate further.
What is happening?
The expected behavior is that the client inserts some data into a database. The data is a timeseries. Each entry to the table has multiple columns. Any one of those column values could change over time.

What the client application does is to select all rows from the database with a particular unique identifier code. All rows with the same unique identifier correspond to the same timeseries.
Each row has a "first seen" and "last observed" datetime. This defines a window for which the data in the row is valid. If it changes, a new row is inserted with a new "first seen" datetime/timestamp.
It orders those rows by "first seen" datetime, and selects the latest row.
It compares the current observed column values with the values from this row.
If they are the same the "last observed" datetime is moved forward to the current timestamp.
If they differ a new row is inserted with the new values and the "first seen" datetime is set to the current timestamp.

This is not working as expected, because for the column containing the "day" values which are converted to a datetime, and represented in the client code as a datetime value, the client reports that some rows differ only by this column, and the values differ by 1 hour. All the values should have a time value of midnight UTC 00:00, but they do not. Some are off by 1 hour.

How can I fix this? (I have fixed the client side code already.)
To "fix" it, the following steps would be required:

update rows which have timezone which is not +00:00.
set the timezone information back to +00:00
since only the date information was initially relevant, the time should not change, all time values should remain 00:00

I tried this:
alter table my_table
add column date_new timestamptz;

update my_table
set date_new = date_column at time zone 'UTC';

It did not change the displayed value. Neither the timezone displayed value nor time displayed value changed.
I considered performing some "hack" using string conversions and string manipulation, but suspect this is probably not the most straight forward approach.
I should note that I would like to keep the time and timezone information. In other words, I do not want to convert the datetime column to a date column.
Change DBeaver Timezone:
How to change DBeaver timezone / How to stop DBeaver from converting date and time
After setting both the DBeaver timezone and Postgres timezone to UTC:
Now, the "bad" data looks like this.
2024-05-05 23:00:00.000 +0000

This should be
2024-05-06 00:00:00.000 +0000

Fix
Here is some useful SQL code which I used to apply the fix. The column containing "bad" data is named price_state_date and the fixed data column is named price_state_date_new.
Set Postgres Timezone and DBeaver Timezone:
select CURRENT_TIME;

show timezone;

set timezone = 'utc';

select CURRENT_TIME;

show timezone;


How to change DBeaver timezone / How to stop DBeaver from converting date and time

Setup new table column
alter table my_table
add column price_state_date_new timestamptz;

Apply fix
update
    my_table
set
    price_state_date_new = price_state_date + interval '1 hour'
where
    extract(hour from price_state_date) = 23
and
    extract(minute from price_state_date) = 0;

Check fix
The following does not select any rows. It casts the time component to a varchar and checks it against the string 00:00:00.
select
    price_state_date,
    price_state_date_new,
    cast(cast(price_state_date_new as time) as varchar) as price_state_date_time_varchar
from
    my_table
where
    cast(cast(price_state_date_new as time) as varchar) not like '00:00:00';

The following does essentially the same thing as the above.
select
    *
from
    my_table
where
    extract(hour from price_state_date_new) != 0
or
    extract(minute from price_state_date_new) != 0
or
    extract(second from price_state_date_new) != 0;

The following query can be used to check how the data has been changed between the old and new columns.
select
    count(*),
    price_state_date,
    price_state_date_new
from
    my_table
group by
    price_state_date,
    price_state_date_new
order by
    price_state_date desc,
    price_state_date_new desc;

Cleanup table
alter table
    my_table
alter column
    price_state_date_new set not null;

alter table
    my_table
drop
    price_state_date;

alter table
    my_table
rename column
    price_state_date_new price_state_date;


There is nothing to fix. timestamptz stores values as UTC, so the timestamp is set to a known value. What you are dealing with Postgres rotating that value to probably the server timezone. Solutions 1) Make server timezone='UTC' 2) Do the conversion on retrieval select  timestamptz_fld AT time zone 'UTC'.

Does this answer your question? Preserve timezone in PostgreSQL timestamptz type. Or any of the other many questions/answers that deal with this Postgres timestamptz.

timestamptz doesn't store timezone information, so your question does not make any sense.  You can't change something in a row when the thing is not stored in the row.  "with timezone" means that the timezone is processed on the way in and the way out, not that the timezone is stored.

@jjanes, technically timestamptz values  do have a time zone namely UTC. That is how you can convert the value using AT TIME ZONE, Postgres knows the stored value is at UTC.

Ok, that's confusing. I'm inspecting the data with DBeaver, and it is currently reporting the timezone as two different values, depending on the date in which the data was inserted. For data which was inserted when the UK was in the same timezone as the UTC timezone, the timezone values are +0000. When the UK moved to BST, the timezone values for rows inserted after this date are +0100.

So I guess the question to answer first would be what causes DBeaver to display multiple rows with different timezones? It must for some reason choose whether it wants to display a timestamptz value as +0000 or +0100. So I would guess there is some additional information embedded into a timestamptz structure, otherwise I can't see how it would switch between different timezones.

Nothing confusing, before the DST change the timestamps are equal to UTC so there is no offset. After the time change they are in BST which is +0100. The times did not change, just their output representation.

@AdrianKlaver Sure, but what causes DBeaver to show both timezones when performing a select query? I understand why it might choose +0100 or +0000, but I don't understand why both are being shown.

Am I correct in thinking that timestamptz causes Postgres to perform some data manipulation or coercion, and that for this reason it would be more sensible to use timestamp instead of timestamptz as this does not perform any additional manipulation either on the way in or out of the database? This would usually be desirable because it makes it much easier to write and debug applications, and I now appear to be discovering in realtime.


You really need to spend time reading up on time zones, in particular as regards the DST transitions. 2) You see two different offsets because you are dealing with two different time zones  for this year, GMT before 2024-03-31 1:00  and BST after the DST transition. So with my server  at set timezone = 'Europe/London'; I get select '2024-03-30 14:00'::timestamptz; 2024-03-30 14:00:00+00 and then select '2024-03-31 14:00'::timestamptz; 2024-03-31 14:00:00+01. The latter translates to UTC as select '2024-03-31 14:00'::timestamptz at time zone  'UTC';  2024-03-31 13:00:00



DBeaver can further complicate issues because it has its own time zone setting that may not match the servers, so a transformation is done. I would suggest using psql while figuring this out, it eliminates another possible layer of confusion. 2) DO NOT use timestamp, that creates an un-anchored timestamp value. With timestamptz you always know the value stored is at UTC so you start at a fixed point.


@AdrianKlaver Every time I have to deal with timezones my head explodes. DST is just more fuel to the fire. How can I query the timezone? Is set timezone persistent? I guess if it is a postgres command it must be persistent to at least some degree, even if it resets after the postgres server is restarted? The reason I am asking this is I don't want to run set timezone ... if I can't set it back to what it has decided the default should be as it is right now. But I think setting it to UTC might simply make the problem disappear.

If you are going to work with timestamps you will need to understand timezones and offsets, there is now way around it. The thumbnail version  is: 1) An offset is just that, a fixed +- offset from UTC.  2) A time zone is a description that describes the offset(s) for a particular location. In your case GMT = UTC +  0 and BST = UTC + 1 and the Europe/London encompasses both as it contains the rules that specify when DST starts and ends. 3) set timezone persists for the database session. To make it 'permanent' you need to change the timezone setting in postgresql.conf.

That won't work, because PostgreSQL does not persist the time zone offset. Instead, it converts the timestamp to UTC and stores it that way internally. The current setting of the parameter timezone in your session controls what time zone offset is displayed, and it also caused the problem that you have now.
Perhaps you can update all timestamps that are exactly at 11pm UTC:
UPDATE my_table
SET date_column = date_column + INTERVAL '1 hour'
WHERE date_column AT TIME ZONE '-01' =
      date_trunc('day', date_column AT TIME ZONE '-01');


This seems like it might be along the right lines, but rather than moving the time back to 23:00, it should be moved forward 1 hour to be 00:00 for the next day.

I thought that's what my statement does. But if you need to add a different interval to make the data correct, go ahead!

I think you're correct, I used a slightly different syntax but essentially the same idea. I think I must have been initially confused when I read this the first time
